# How do you remove attributes from a node using Groovy's XMLSlurper and GPathResult?

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper, gpath

I need to remove the attributes from a body node in some parsed HTML (converted to XML).

Answer (score 5):

Call the `attributes()` on the element that contains the attribute and then call `remove('attr name')` as shown below.

```
attributes().remove('attr name')
```

You can read more details here.

Comment: Ah, I couldn't see the attributes() method in the documentation. Thanks for the pointer and also see the final method I came up with.

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * Remove all attributes from the root body tag
 */
def removeBodyAttributes() {
    def attributeNames = bodyXml.attributes().collect {it.key}
    println attributeNames
    println bodyXml.attributes()
    attributeNames.each {bodyXml.attributes().remove(it)}
    println bodyXml.attributes()
}
```